# Two 20 amp circuit breakers installed with copper wire bridge

Tags: 240v

We hired an electrician to Power a steam humidifier and when I opened the electrical panel I was surprised to see two 20 amp circuit breakers next to each other with a copper wire through the on/off switch connecting both breakers and ensuring both were moved on and off together. I have only seen dual switches with a common "bridge" to both that come that way from the manufacturer.

Why would the electrician install it this way and is this a safe feature in the panel...?

Comment: What is this linked pair of breakers powering?

Comment: All single pole GE breakers have a hole in the tab which allows connecting two adjacent breakers for manual switching. For modern breakers this does not mean common trip. For older breakers this may provide common trip.

Comment: We need to know more about what these breakers are powering, so we can figure out whether they require *common trip* or whether *common maintenance shutoff* will suffice.  Regardless, a piece of wire (I've also seen a nail) is not acceptable as a handle-tie.  The breaker manufacturers will cheerfully sell you a proper and **UL listed** handle-tie.

Answer (score 3):

The nail/wire is not a legal handle tie, but a proper electrical supply who deals in that brand will cheerfully sell you one for $3 - or as Ed Beal points out, *anyone* will sell you a 2-pole breaker for $9.  Whether that is legal: It depends.

If the breakers are powering device(s) that use *both* 120V *and* 240V (classically ovens (for the light) and dryers (for the motor)), then that device requires **common-trip**.  Handle-ties cannot provide common trip.  Only a 2-pole breaker can do that.

If the breakers are powering a variety of loads, *every single one of which is a 120V-to-neutral load*, or every single one is 240V-only (no neutral: water heater, A/C, EV charger), then common trip is not required; you need **common maintenance shutoff**.  That is what a handle-tie does.  But you need to use the proper one that is **UL listed** for the breaker type.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: a 240V *only* device (HWH, AC) can use a common maintenance shutoff just fine.  It's only devices or circuits with *both* 120V and 240V loads (both L-L- and L-N) that require the common trip functionality

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks.  Thought of throwing your hat in the ring for moderator?  I can't take it, the eligibility window is at a time when I'm awaiting data that'll require me to make a huge life-path decision.

Comment: I'm kind of taking a wait-and-see -- I know some diamond mods from other SEs though so I might talk to them about it

Answer (score 1):

Although a 6 penny nail that was cut off was common in years past nails and wire are not legal handle ties. Manfacturers do make snap in ties but they are harder to find today than a double pole breaker that would meet code requirements where the wire is not code compliant. I state this as long as the panel is still supported double pole breakers are quite inexpensive for a common brand at 20 amps and this would be safer.